# Como recuperar datos de un Form en un modal y pasarlo a un Form principal

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, bootstrap, modal

es practicamente lo del titulo.
Tengo un Form principal, dentro de el tengo un boton que despliega un modal en el cual el contenido de este modal se muestra a traves de un `<iframe>`, al presionar guardar en el modal invoco a un metodo llamado recibir() desde el controller, que no hace mas que recuperar los 4 datos desde el Form del modal.

```
public function recibir(Request $request){
    return $request->all();
}
```

Entonces necesito pasar la informacion de ese Form del modal al Form principal para poder guardar todos los datos que necesito.
De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y ademas ganaras tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Revisa [mcve] para que agregues mas código mínimo con el que se pueda ver lo que realizas. Por ejemplo podrías agregar la parte del `Form` y `Ajax`

Comment: la opcion mas sencilla es usar un poco de js son menos lineas y menos carga para el servidor, te recomendaria vuejs solo necesitas saber usar v-model y la estructura basica de vue con conocimientos basicos de js.
https://styde.net/curso-de-vue-2/

Comment: Enviar un request al server para que nada más te lo devuelva? Agrega el código del frontend, y podemos ver para hacer lo que quieres con js.

Answer (score 0):

Deduzco que la llamada a la función **recibir** es mediante ajax, por lo que deberías devolverlo en formato JSON. Algo como:

```
return Response::json($request->all());
```